# How to input the name of the file you want to open?

Tags: c

I know that code will not run but how can i fix this? ( I am new to c)

```
  char name[20]  
  printf("Ender the name of text file you want to open ex: word.txt");
  scanf("%s", name);
  ptr = fopen("name", "r"); // There is the problem
```

Comment: `scanf("%19[^\n]", name); ptr = fopen(name, "r");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char name[20];  //Missed the semi colon
printf("Ender the name of text file you want to open ex: word.txt");
scanf("%s", name);
ptr = fopen(name, "r"); // Remove the string literal.
```

Using "name" means you are looking for a file named "name" in your directory to open.
If you use name instead (no quotes) then you are looking for the string literal that is stored in the variable named name.

Comment: In addition your ptr is of type FILE *

Comment: OP did **not** "miss the `&`"!!! No need for `&` in the case of arrays, as `(void*)name == (void*)&name`.

Comment: In addition, the statement "Using `"name"` is like telling the compiler..." is also misleading, as the file is opened **only during runtime**. The compiler knows nothing about it!!!

Answer (score 2):

By calling `fopen("name","r")`, you are attempting to open a file called "name" for reading.

---

Assuming that you have `FILE* ptr` declared somewhere up there...

**Change this:**

```
ptr = fopen("name","r");
```

**To this:**

```
ptr = fopen(name,"r");
```

Comment: Would be perfect if you also explained why.

Comment: @user3623727: add `printff("%s", name);` after `scanf("%s", name);` and check the output...

Answer (score 0):

Just simply pass name instead:

```
if ((ptr = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "We have a problem!\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Also, do some error checking to ensure it is really open.

Answer (score 0):

For file I/O, you need a `FILE` object, hence the code would be:

```
FILE* ptr;
ptr = fopen( name, "r" );
```

and also check the return value, that will be `NULL` in case of failure.

Check out [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) for more details.